# What service account permissions should I set for secure flexible app engine -> cloud function communication

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am having problems identifying which service account I need to give certain roles to.

I have a NodeJS app running on my flexible app engine environment.
I have a single hello-world python3.7 HTTP cloud function.

I want to do a GET request from my app engine to my cloud function.

When the allUser member is given the Cloud Function Invoker role on the hello-world cloud function everything works fine.

But now I want to secure my cloud function endpoint so that only my flexible app engine can reach it.

I remove the allUser member and as expected I get a 403 when the app engine tries to call.

Now I add the @appspot.gserviceaccount.com and @gae-api-prod.google.com.iam.gserviceaccount.com members to the hello-world cloud function and give them Cloud Function Invoker roles.

I would expect the flexible app engine to now be able to call the hello-world cloud function seeing as I gave it the Cloud Function Invoker role.

But I keep getting a 403 error.

What service account is app engine flexible using to do these calls to the cloud function API?

Comment: You are on the right track. Next, request an Identity Token from the metadata server and including that token in the "Authorization: Bearer ID_TOKEN" HTTP header for requests to Cloud Functions. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/verifying-instance-identity#request_signature

Comment: Note: Identity-based authorization does not require any roles to be assigned to the service account. The identity of the service account is used for authorization and not the roles assigned to the service account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

John Hanley was correct,

When using GCP libraries to perform actions (like google-cloud-firestore for example) the executing function will use the underlying service account permissions to do those actions.

When doing manual HTTP requests to cloud function URLs, you will have to fetch a token from the metadata server to properly authenticate your request.

```py
def generate_token() -> str:
    """Generate a Google-signed OAuth ID token"""
    token_request_url: str = f'http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service- 
    accounts/default/identity?audience={TARGET_URL}'
    token_request_headers: dict = {'Metadata-Flavor': 'Google'}

    token_response = requests.get(token_request_url, headers=token_request_headers)
    return token_response.content.decode("utf-8")

def do_request():
    token: str = generate_token()

    headers: dict = {
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}'
    }

    requests.post(url=TARGET_URL, json=data, headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

The are some settings to made in order to connect cloud functions wit a service account:

- Enable required APIs
- Enable Service account
- Act as User Service Account

The default service account creates a cloud function and sometimes doesn't have all the privileges.

You can find more info Here:

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/